# Problema formato al obtener el nombre de una hoja excell en VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vb

Por ridículo que parezca tengo un problema a la hora de obtener el nombre de una **hoja Excel** debido a que me la escribe en formato fecha.
La Hoja tiene por **nombre JUL02** y quiero obtener exactamente el literal "JUL02", sin embargo, a la hora de leer el nombre de la hoja y escribirla en una celda lo que escribe es 02-jul, como si fuera una fecha.
Tan sencillo como:

```
resNam = Workbook.Worksheets(l).Name  
Workbook.Worksheets.Cells(a, b) = resNam
```

Ya he probado con CStr tanto `CStr(Workbook.Worksheets(l).Name)` como `CStr(resNam)`, pero sigue poniéndo lo mismo.
Cualquier ayuda o enfoque se agradece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente obtienes de forma correcta el nombre de tu hoja, lo que te falta hacer es dar formato a la columna donde almacenas el dato, por más que conviertas de tipo String tu variable si el formato de la columna es diferente no te va a funcionar.. Con este código funciona perfectamente.

```
resNam = ActiveSheet.Name
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,4).Value = resNam
ActiveSheet.Cells(1,4).NumberFormat = "@"
```

en tu caso podrías agregar esta línea:

```
Workbook.Worksheets.Cells(a, b).NumberFormat = "@"
```

Espero te sirva, estoy a la orden.